# How does range-for iterator class work?

Tags: c++, for-loop, iterator

I do know, how this code works:

```
std::vector<int> sth;
for (auto const & elem : sth) { }
```

However, this code is mysterious for me:

```
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
for(auto & file : fs::directory_iterator("some/path"))
    std::cout << file << std::endl;
```

How does this class (`std::filesystem::directory_iterator`) work, that it enable me iterate through entire container? As far as I know, the range-for works like this:

```
// given "container"
for(auto it = std::begin(container); it != std::end(container); it++)
{
}
```

How it is possible in case of passing `directory_iterator` as `container` here?

Comment: Range iteration works for any class that implements `begin()` and `end()` methods. This `fd::directory_iterator` simply needs to implement these two methods (or declare specializations for `std::begin` and `std::end`). You've almost reached the point when you realize how awesome C++ is.

Comment: I've reached this point, but then I've read about Unicode support in C++ ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Range-based for is syntactic sugar for a traditional for loop

All it does is execute a for loop over a range.

It is a more readable equivalent to the traditional for loop operating over a range of values, such as all elements in a container.

Under the hood, the compiler will convert a range-based for loop into something like the following:

```
{
    auto && __range = range_expression ; 
    for (auto __begin = begin_expr, __end = end_expr; __begin != __end; ++__begin) 
    { 
        range_declaration = *__begin; 
        loop_statement 
    } 
}
```

`begin_expr` and `end_expr` are defined as follows:

- If *`range_expression`* is an expression of **array** type, then `begin_expr` is `__range` and `end_expr` is `(__range + __bound)`, where `__bound` is the number of elements in the array (if the array has unknown size or is of an incomplete type, the program is ill-formed)
- If *`range_expression`* is an expression of a **class type** `C` that has a member named `begin` and/or a member named `end` (regardless of the type or accessibility of such member), then `begin_expr` is `__range.begin()` and `end_expr` is `__range.end();`
- Otherwise, `begin_expr` is `begin(__range)` and `end_expr` is `end(__range)`, which are found via argument-dependent lookup (non-ADL lookup is not performed).

**`std::filesystem::directory_iterator`**

In the case of `directory_iterator` it is the third option above, in that it has [`begin` and `end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator/begin) non-member functions which allows it to be used in range-based for loops.

Comment: A note that C++17 changes the expression slightly might be of value.